# How can I properly import this .OBJ file?

Tags: texturing, game-engine, import

I'm encountering a problem with the following .OBJ. It is a rip-off of the Destiny Islands world in Kingdom Hearts. Here is the link:
http://www.models-resource.com/psp/khbirthbysleep/model/2856/
I am in Blender Game and using the latest version of Blender from the official website.
When I try to import it, I immediately notice that there went something wrong: The leafs on the trees have white borders around them, the sand near the water doesn't load correctly. Here is a screenshot from within Blender:
[image: Destiny Islands bug]

When I test the game, everything looks even worse: the texture order gets messed up; the texture under the bridge appears above it, etc. It looks really weird. I don't know how to fix it. Maybe there is something wrong with the .OBJ or is there an import mode that fixes this problem?

Thanks in advance and please excuse my bad English.

Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The trees use alpha maps, and you can see these inside the 3d view, It is meant to be like that until you apply materials.
2. I'm not sure if this is the case but if it is then this may help. For the water there are 3 things I could think of:

   - The.OBJ is so big, that when you zoom out you can't see the water since the 3d view cannot trace that far back. So try zooming into the water.
   - Try removing doubles by pressing T in the 3D View, and on the left you should see remove doubles button. Also try and recalculate normals, which is right under remove doubles.
   - Since the model is ripped, the model just might be clipped and the person who ripped it might not have gotten all the water polys.
   - Select the water and try and move it upwards, from the image it looks like it's colliding with the sand instead of being above it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I will give the result in a minute.

Comment: Nope, removing doubles and recalcullating normals didn't help.

Comment: Ok , select the water and try and move it upwards , from the image it looks like its colliding with the sand instead of being above it

Comment: I found out what the problem with the water is. There simply is no water on the sand. As you said, it is colliding with the sand, but it is unconnected to the visible water.

Comment: Sweet , i have edited the answer with the solution , Please check it so people know we have resolved the problem :)